Why is assigning a function to window in a module not working?
module.mjs
console.log('module1 loaded');

window.module1_function = () => {
   console.log('module1_function executed');
   return 42;
}

index.html
<script defer type="module" src="./js/module1.mjs"></script>

<script defer>
   module1_function();
</script>

Output
Uncaught ReferenceError: module1_function is not defined

module1 loaded

As you can see it fails. When called the function is not defined. The module is not loaded until after the function is called. Executing module1_function() in the console the function runs successfully.
Why?
defer should cause the inline script to not be processed until after module.mjs has executed, at which point the function should be assigned and available.
How do I make the function in this module available for use in a script? I do not want to have to turn my script into a module and import the function.

"I do not want to have to turn my script into a module" - then don't use <script type='module'>

Inline scripts cannot defer, they run synchronously. You have to use an external script with src to defer. Only inline script modules can defer.

To clarify. module.mjs has to be a module since it's reusing code from other modules. However, when module.mjs is added to an HTML file I'd like to be able to use it from other scripts without having to turn my other scripts into modules too.

To access module1_function from the window object in a non-module script, the easiest solution to me seems to add a load event listener into your non-module script:
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  console.log(typeof window.module1_function); // should log 'function' 
});
</script>

That should wait for anything to be loaded (even scripts with async attribute) before executing the callback.
FYI MDN says the following regarding modules and the defer attribute (point 3):

There is no need to use the defer attribute [...] when loading a module script; modules are deferred automatically.

OTOH another option you have would be dynamic imports - with the additional benefit that you don't need to attach the function to the global scope at all (at least you shouldn't have to do it). However, the module code you've shown does not export anything so you'd have to change that, too:
In module1.mjs:
export const module1_function = () => {
  console.log('module1_function executed');
  return 42;
};

And inside the HTML:
<script>
import('./js/module1.mjs').then((module) => {
  module.module1_function();
});
</script>

